# Multicluster istio command for services

Tags: istio

Working with a multicluster istio mesh:

is there a command or series of commands to get all the names of services on the other clusters

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get all the names of services on the other clusters. The `kubectl` command, which returns the results you want, only works on its own cluster. If you want to collect data from each other cluster, you must log on to each cluster and execute `kubectl` commands separately.

You can of course create a script for this if you want to automate the process. In this case, it will be very helpful to use `context`. Look how to [configure access to multiple clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)`.